# How to get the string value of the item selected from a listview

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a custom adaptor that is fills a listview with artists names. I want to click on the listview artist and it will return me the list of songs by the artist. I want to get the string value of the artist when i click on the listview and compare it against an arraylist of all the songs

```
   public void getSongList() {
            //retrieve song info
            ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
             musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
            if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
                //get columns
                int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                //add songs to list
                do {

                    long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                    String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                    songs.add(new Song(thisId,thisTitle,thisArtist));}
                while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }

        }




      artistLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"am:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ArrayList<Song> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Song song : songs){
    strong text
                        if (song.getArtist().equals("Foo Fighters")){
                            temp.add(song);
                        }
                    }
                    songs = temp;
                    SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getApplication(), songs);
                    artistLV.setAdapter(songAdt);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Song selectedSong = songs.get(i); // this will object of data of the selected song
```

then use

```
selectedSong.getArtist();
```

and it will return you the artist of the song that you selected

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines inside your onItemClick method

```
TextView artistTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewReference);
String artistName= artistTextView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: How it is going to give detail of selected item of listview

Comment: there are two ways which i know you can retrieve data from listview rows first way is the one which @Jawad has told and second one is like this